# simple social network using node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I am trying to build simple social network and I am following this book(Building Node Applications with MongoDB and Backbone)(https://github.com/Swiftam/book-node-mongodb-backbone/tree/master/ch10). However, I just realized that the node.js version has been updated.

I tied to solve some the issue however I got problem in chat.js that states this is the error:

> ch10/routes/chat.js:27
>  data.sessionStore.load(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

```
module.exports = function(app, models) {

var io = require('socket.io');
var utils = require('connect').utils;
var cookie = require('cookie');
    this.io = io;

//var Session = require('connect').middleware.session.Session;

var sio = io.listen(app.server);

sio.configure(function() {

    // Utility methods to see if the account is online
    app.isAccountOnline = function(accountId) {
        var clients = sio.sockets.clients(accountId);
        return (clients.length > 0);
    };

    sio.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {

        var signedCookies = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
    //  var cookies = utils.parseSignedCookies(signedCookies, app.sessionSecret);

    //  data.sessionID = cookies['express.sid'];
        data.sessionStore = app.sessionStore;
        data.sessionStore.load(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
         if (err || !session) {
          accept("Error", false);
             } else {
           data.session = session;
           accept(null, true);
             }
        });
    });

    sio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        var session = socket.handshake.session;
        var accountId = session.accountId;
        var sAccount = null;
        socket.join(accountId);
                    io.use(function (socket, next) { next(); });
        // Immediately trigger the login event
        // of this account
        app.triggerEvent('event:' + accountId, {
            from: accountId,
            action: 'login'
        });

        var handleContactEvent = function(eventMessage) {
            socket.emit('contactEvent', eventMessage);
        };

        var subscribeToAccount = function(accountId) {
            var eventName = 'event:' + accountId;
            app.addEventListener(eventName, handleContactEvent);
            console.log('Subscribing to ' + eventName);
        };

        // Find the account contacts and subscribe
        models.Account.findById(accountId, function subscribeToFriendFeed(account) {
            var subscribedAccounts = {};
            sAccount = account;
            account.contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
                if (!subscribedAccounts[contact.accountId]) {
                    subscribeToAccount(contact.accountId);
                    subscribedAccounts[contact.accountId] = true;
                }
            });

            // Subscribed to my feed as well
            if (!subscribedAccounts[accountId]) {
                subscribeToAccount(accountId);
            }
        });

        // Remove listeners if socket disconnects
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            sAccount.contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
                var eventName = 'event:' + contact.accountId;
                app.removeEventListener(eventName, handleContactEvent);
                console.log('Unsubscribing from ' + eventName);
            });
            app.triggerEvent('event:' + accountId, {
                from: accountId,
                action: 'logout'
            });
        });
                      var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')(SESSION_SECRET);    

            // ### Cookie parser

                // Wrapper arround Express cookie parser, so we can use the same cookie parser for socket.io.
                // Parse Cookie header and populate `socket.request.cookies` with an object keyed by the cookie names.
                // Uses signed cookies by passing a secret string, which assigns `socket.request.secret` so it may be used by other middleware.

          function cookieParserWrapper (socket, next) {
            // request, response and callback
          cookieParser(socket.request, {}, next);
            }


        // Handle incoming chats from client
        socket.on('chatclient', function(data) {
            sio.sockets.in(data.to).emit('chatserver', {
                from: accountId,
                text: data.text
            });
        });
    });

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing the code myself or anything.

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined"

That particular error means that data.sessionStore is undefined and that "load" does not exists as a property, since there is literally nothing defined in data.sessionStore.

So the problem in my opinion is that your session system is not working properly. Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks, but the memorystroe, I commented because it is decrypted in the new node.js version. So could you tell me how to fix the sessionStore?
//var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore;
//app.sessionStore = new MemoryStore();

Comment: This link should point you in the right direction.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420051/store-session-data-using-memorystore-in-node-similar-to-sessiondata-val